# Convex functions of a martingale.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, jensen-inequality

> Let $X_1(t)=e^{B(t)}$ and $X_2(t)=e^{-B(t)}$ where $B(t)$ is the standard brownian motion and $\{G_t\}$ is the filtration generated by the brownian motion. Determine what kind of martingale $X_1(t)$ and $X_2(t)$ are.

I'm fairly certain this comes out trivial as they're both $\{G_t\}$-measurable, and convex functions, so by jensens inequality for martingales they're both submartingales.

Is there a way that could result in a stronger statement for one of these?

Comment: They are not martingales since $e^{\pm B_t}=1\pm\int_0^t e^{\pm B_t}dB_t+\int_0^t e^{\pm B_t}dt.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least four ways to answer this question.

1. As you pointed out in your answer, use the fact that if $M_t$ is a martingale and $f(\cdot)$ is convex then $f(M_t)$ is a submartingale.
2. Apply Jensen's inequality directly to $\mathbb{E}\left[e^{B_t}\right]$. By "conditional version" of Jensen's inequality we have
   $$ \mathbb{E}\left[e^{B_t}|\mathcal{F_s}\right] > e^{\mathbb{E}[ B_t|\mathcal{F_s}]}=e^{B_s} $$
   since $f(\cdot)$ is strictly convex.
3. As Surb suggested in his comment, use Ito's Lemma to obtain
   $$ e^{B_t}= 1 + \int_0^t e^{B_s}dB_s + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t e^{B_s}ds,$$
4. (My personal favorite) Use the moment generating function of $B_t$. We know that $B_t\sim \mathcal{N}(0,t)$ and so $$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{uB_t}\right]=e^{\frac{1}{2}u^2t}$$
   From this we conclude that, for any $u\in\mathbb{R}$, we have 
   $$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{uB_t}|\mathcal{F_s}\right]=e^{uB_s}\mathbb{E}\left[e^{u(B_t-B_s)}|\mathcal{F_s}\right]=e^{uB_s}\mathbb{E}\left[e^{u(B_t-B_s)}\right]=e^{uB_s}e^{\frac{1}{2}u^2(t-s)}>e^{uB_s} $$

Comment: This was incredibly insightful, especially the fourth method, thank you!  I had some concern jumping to jensens inequality since a Martingale is also a Sub-martingale, and it left me wondering if it required greater care.

Comment: @OGV You're welcome. If you liked the answer you can accept it or/and upvote it :)